# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradatasql [10076] Failed to execute script pyinstalletest

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, teradata, teradatasql

i'm trying to create a exe which import some data into teradata.As a test script i'm trying to connect Teradata using below code. i can able to successfully connect in my local.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

user = 'dbc'
pasw=user
host = '192.168.1.7'
# connect
td_engine = create_engine('teradatasql://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host + '')
sql="select * from dbc.usersV"
x=td_engine.execute(sql)
```

i have generate the exe using below command.

```
pyinstaller --add-binary "C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\teradatasql\teradatasql.dll;teradatasql" -F pyinstalletest.py
```

once the exe is generated i'm trying to execute the exe and i'm getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstalletest.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 61, in create
  File "sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
  File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 267, in load
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradatasql
[10076] Failed to execute script pyinstalletest
```

i have gone through various links but no luck. please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: You may need to explicitly include the actual dialect package `teradatasqlalchemy` not just the `teradatasql` driver it uses. Not familiar enough with pyinstaller to say exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

The similar question has been answered here: [Source](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3518)

> To get the Teradata Queries to run on the .exe produced by Pyinstaller. I changed my engine from SQLAlchemy to Teradata

From :

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
user, pasw, hostname = UserName,Password, 'myurl.com'
# connect
td_engine = sa.create_engine('teradata://{}:{}@{}:22/'.format(user,pasw,hostname),echo=True)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query1,connect)
```

To:

```
import teradata
user, pasw, hostname = UserName,Password, 'myurl.com'
td = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=True)
td_engine = td.connect(method="odbc",system=hostname, username=user,password=pasw,driver="Teradata")
```

Comment: my question completely differ from the one you posted.please note i want to import data from pandas df to teradata. In that case sqlalchemy engine connection should be passed as connection param for to_sql clause.